# gccgo dynamic linking and modules

Tags: go, linker, gccgo

Compiling an executable with gccgo creates a dynamically linked executable, linked against libgo.so. I am using gccgo-11 on ubuntu 20.04, pulled from apt.

The resulting executable is small, as expected. About 50Kb for a basic hello world.

As soon as I start using external modules (in this case viper and gorilla/websocket) the executable size starts creeping back to the original, statically linked size (~9MB).
If I compile with go alone (not using gccgo) the exeutable is about 9MB also.

This look to me, like the modules are compiled separately, and statically, and then linked, statically into the final executable.

Am I overlooking something here? Is there some option that must be enabled?

I would expect the module dependencies to also be compiled by gccgo, and linked dynamically against the shared libgo.so.